# Lseek not working

Tags: c, file-descriptor, lseek

i am trying to check the size of my txt files using lseek. Unfortunately i doesnt work.
My T.Txt contains 16 characters:ABCDABCDDABCDABCD nothing more. So the number variables should have 16+1. Why it is 19 instead? The second problem why i cant use
SEEK_END-1 to start from last position-1.? I would be grateful for help with that.

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd1 = open("T.txt", O_RDONLY);
    long  number;

    if (fd1 < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    number = lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_END); 
    printf("FILE size PROGRAM>C: %ld\n", number);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because of a BOM.

Comment: OT: `lseek()` returns `off_t` not `long`.

Comment: `SEEK_END` is not a "number" as such, it is an `enum`. Basically it is a way to tell `lseek()` where to skip to in the file. You cannot (reasonably) do arithmetic on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because of the `\r\n` characters in your file, which stand for newline on Windows systems.

On my machine (Mac OS X 10.10) your code gives the right result for your file, provided it doesn't have any newline character on the end, i.e. only the string: `ABCDABCDDABCDABCD` (output is then: 17).

You use the `lseek()` function correctly except that the result of `lseek()` is `off_t` not a `long`.

Comment: what about SEEK_END -1? Why instead of 18 i am getting 0 ?

Comment: @user3402584: SEEK_END is a constant -- `2` in most implementations. You change it to `1`, which is the constant for `SEEK_CUR`. You are misunderstanding its purpose; it's only to tell what the *other* argument of `seek` means.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your text file contains a BOM header `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`.
Try to print the file contents in HEX and see if it prints these extra 3 characters.

You can learn more about [file headers and BOM here].(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)